# enable drag and drop VML shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm using Raphael to render some text.

I would like to be able to click and drag this text into a different container... for instance... the address bar...  using IE7.

Ultimately i'll be adding my own data to the dataTransfer object, but just getting it draggable would be a start.

Preference would be to achieve this before insanity robs me blind.

here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8c37/1/embedded/result/) - it's embedded because jsf doesnt work in IE7 mode.

many thanks.

some code to satisfy SO `im code!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for what it's worth - my workaround was to remove the Raphael rendered text and replace with stock HTML and move it manually, this gave me the drag and drop I wanted.